# Typescript: How do you narrow a type union to one part? Eg. I have type {error:true} | {error:false} and I want type {error:true}

Tags: typescript

I have a type `{error:true} | {error:false}` and I want to convert it into the type `{error: true}` using only the type system.

I know I can narrow it with an if statement

```
const x: {error:true} | {error:false} = {error:true}
if (x.error) {
// x is narrowed to type {error: true}
} else {
// x is narrowed to type {error: false}
}
```

Thanks in advance for answering such a basic question, I can't seem to figure it out. Maybe its not possible?

**Use case:**

The desire to narrow a type has come up a few times. The latest time
I had an api `ReturnType` that `ErrorType | SuccessType` and wanted to type the error and success callbacks with `ErrorType` and `SuccessType` seperately. Specifically:

Declare a contract for the API:

```
export const API_FORM_TAG_SET = createFormUrl(
    '/api/forms/tag/set',
    z.object({thing_id: z.string().uuid()}),
    z.array(z.object({tag_id: z.string(), value: z.boolean()})))
    <{ errors: string[] }, { tags: {[key:string]:tag} }>();
```

where createFormUrl is:

```
export type FormErrorType = { errors: string[] };
export type FormUrl<Q, B, ErrorType, SuccessType> = ApiUrl<Q, B, (ErrorType & FormErrorType) | SuccessType>;

export function createFormUrl<ZQ extends Zod.Schema, ZB extends Zod.Schema>(path, querySchema: ZQ, bodySchema: ZB)
    : <E, S>() => FormUrl<getZodType<ZQ>, getZodType<ZB>, E, S> {
    type Q = getZodType<ZQ>;
    type B = getZodType<ZB>;
    return <E, S>(): FormUrl<Q, B, E, S> => {
        return new ApiUrl<Q, B, (E & FormErrorType) | S>(path, querySchema, bodySchema);
    }
}
```

On the client use the contract to define the input type, output error type, and output success type:

```
const handleSubmit = createHandleSubmit(API_FORM_TAG_SET,
        (element) => tags.map(({tag_id}) => ({tag_id, value: !!(element[tag_id].checked)})),
        (res) => setErrors(res.errors),
        (res) => { setTagState(res.tags)},
        {thing_id});
```

where createHandleSubmit3 is:

```
export function createHandleSubmit<Q,B,E,S>(apiUrl: FormUrl<Q, B, E, S>,
    formToData: (element: HTMLElement) => B,
    reject: (res: E & FormErrorType) => void, resolve: (res: S) => void, 
    query?: Q){
    return async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const data = formToData(event.target);
        const res =  await apiUrl.post(query as Q, data as B);
        if ("errors" in res.data) {
            reject(res.data);
        } else {
            resolve(res.data);
        }
    }
}
```

By using Extract<ResponseType, FormErrorType> in [form utils][4] I can avoid creating the FormUrl type and the corresponding create function. (thanks @jcalz)

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to do?  Maybe write some code that shows how you'd like to use it?  It sounds like *maybe* you're asking for a block-scoped type assertion (sort of like `x as {error: true}` but the narrowing persists to subsequent lines), but I can't be sure.  Narrowing generally only happens via control flow analysis, and that involves code that makes it to runtime; it's not "only the type system".  So, uh, what's the use case?

Comment: @jcalz: my guess is OP seeks for something similar to Except/Omit that would work in this scenario

Comment: Well, `Extract<{error: true} | {error: false}, {error: true}>` is an overly complicated way to write `{error: true}`, so I'd really like to see a use case here

Comment: I'd also like to see a usecase for this.

Comment: Updated with a use case that's probably really dumb. Though I think Extract does what I want! Thanks! I should not have just skimmed the utility page :/

Comment: @evandwight I don't think it is a dumb use case but I do think the root problem here might be that you're not sure how to efficiently **describe** what you specifically want which is most of the battle towards finding the correct solution. A more concrete example of what types you are working with and how you want to manipulate them would be helpful for us to aid you :)

Comment: Could you include whatever is needed to understand the use case as plaintext within the question itself?  We can't require that someone navigate to github in order to find the relevant example... and such an example should ideally be self-contained and not rely on zod/axios unless your question depends on them.  `Extract` is useful, but not when you have to write out the type you care about multiple times, so a self-contained plain-text [mre] would still be helpful here.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for answering my question. I attempted to add the relevant parts of the code directly on stackoverflow. However, I'm not sure how to remove zod from the minimal reproducible example as defining the schema for the api is a core part of the use case. Thank you for your patience and explaining proper etiquette.